# VS2022のNuGetパッケージマネージャー

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

VS2022のNuGetパッケージマネージャーの「参照」でNugetパッケージの一覧が出てきますが、リストには25個以上表示されません。「検索」にパッケージ名を入れると検索はできるのでインストールできないというわけではないのですが、VS2019ではリストを下にスクロールしていくと次々と表示されていたので、これがVS2022の仕様なのかバグなのか知りたいところです。

VS2022のバージョン：17.8.3
NuGetパッケージマネージャー : 6.8.0

Comment: 自分の環境（Windows 10、他は質問者さんと同じ）でも同じです。バグではないと思います（仕様だという Microsoft のドキュメントは見つかりませんが）。なんでそんなことが気になるのですか？

Comment: 自作のNuGetパッケージをローカルドライブに入れて、そこからもパッケージを検索できるようにしています。そのローカルのNuGetパッケージをリストアップしたときに追加した新しいパッケージが表示されず、VS2019ではそこにある分すべて表示されるのにと思って質問した次第です。検索すれば出てくるのでおそらく仕様なのでしょうね。